# Which hash algorithm can be used for duplicate content verification?

Tags: java, hash, md5

I have an xml file, where I need to determine if it is a duplicate or not.

I will either hash the entire xml file, or specific xml nodes in the xml file will be used to then generate some kind of hash.

Is md5 suitable for this?

Or something else?  Speed in generation of the hash is also fairly important, but the guarantee to produce a unique hash for unique data is of higher important.

Comment: if nobody is trying to "attack" you by placing forged file, MD5 is fine.  If security is a concern, like in DVCSes, then something like SHA-1 should be your friend.  *Git* is using SHA-1 and here's why you *shall not* have collision on your data set: http://seejeffrun.blogspot.com/2009/08/hash-collisions-in-git.html

Answer (score 8):

MD5 is broken (in the sense that it's possible to intentionally generate a hash collision), you should probably use the SHA family (eg: SHA-256 or SHA-2) if you are concerned about someone *maliciously* creating a file with the same hash as another file.

---

Note that hash functions, by their nature, cannot guarantee a unique hash for every possible input. Hash functions have a limited length (eg: MD5 is 128 bits in length, so there are 2<sup>128</sup> possible hashes). You can't map a potentially infinite domain to a finite co-domain, this is mathematically impossible.

However, as per [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), the chances of a collision in a good hash function is 1 in 2<sup>n/2</sup>, where n is the length in bits. (eg: With 128-bit MD5 that would be 2<sup>64</sup>). This is so statistically insignificant that you don't have to worry about a collision happening by accident.

Comment: Comments purged, discussion [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5325/discussion-between-nulluserexception-and-user988052)

Comment: It doesn't play any role in this use case that MD5 is broken, right?

Answer (score 4):

MD5 is suitable and fast. Note though that a single difference in one character will produce a completely different MD5.

There is a slight chance that MD5 will produce the same hash for different inputs. This will be pretty rare. So, depending on your input (are you expecting many similar XMLs or many different ones?) when MD5 gives you a positive match you can compare the plain String contents.

Comment: Is there any way to detect duplicate content when there is some small change? Or will it always be considered new content?

Answer (score 0):

If someone can alter at least partially the contents of some of the XML files, and that someone has an advantage in making you declare two XML files (or XML excerpts) identical while in fact they are not, then you need a cryptographically secure hash function, namely one which is resistant to *collisions*. A collision is a pair of distinct messages (sequences of bytes) which yield the same hash output -- exactly what you would like to avoid. Since a hash function accepts inputs longer than its output, collisions necessarily exist; a hash function is deemed cryptographically secure when nobody can actually *produce* such a collision.

If a hash function outputs *n* bits, then one can expect to find a collision after hashing about *2<sup>n/2</sup>* distinct messages. A secure hash function is a hash function such that no method is known to get a collision faster than that.

If there is no security issue (i.e. nobody will actively try to find a collision, you just fear a collision out of bad luck), then cryptographically weak hash functions are an option, provided that they have a large enough output, so that *2<sup>n/2</sup>* remains way bigger than the expected number of XML files you will compare. For *n = 128* (i.e. *2<sup>n/2</sup>* close to eighteen billions of billions), MD5 is fine, fast and widely supported. You may want to investigate [MD4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1320), which is even weaker, but a bit faster too. If you want a larger *n*, try [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1), which offers 160-bit outputs (also, SHA-1 weaknesses are still theoretical at the moment, so SHA-1 is much less "cryptographically broken" than MD5).

If you have, even potentially, security issues, then go for [SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2). No cryptographic weakness with regards to collisions is currently known for that function. If you run into performance issues (which is rather improbable: on a basic PC, SHA-256 can process more than 100 megabytes of data per second, so chances are that XML parsing will be widely more expensive than hashing), consider SHA-512, which is somewhat faster on platforms which offer 64-bit integer types (but quite slower on platforms which do not).

Note that all these hash functions are about sequences of bytes. A single flipped bit changes the output. In the XML world, a given document can be encoded in various ways which are semantically identical, but distinct as far as bits on the wire are concerned (e.g. `&eacute;` and `&#233` both represent the same character `é`). It is up to you to define which notion of equality you want to use; see [canonical XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML).